# cannot find /lib/libc.so.6 even after setting sysroot

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I am getting error like this

```
gcc/i586-rdk-linux/4.8.3/ld: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
gcc/i586-rdk-linux/4.8.3/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the command i am giving.

```
$ i586-rdk-linux-g++  -m32 -march=i586 --sysroot=$(SYSROOT) ./obj/*.o -fPIC  -shared -o libmine.so -L$(LDOPTS)
```

It seems like linker is searching for libc.so.6 in /lib/ eventhough i am setting sysroot. Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding `-Wl--sysroot=$(SYSROOT)`, which passes the option to `ld`.

Comment: It is not working.i586-rdk-linux-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wl--sysroot=

Comment: Crap, forgot a comma: `-Wl,--sysroot=$(SYSROOT)`