# ld.exe cannot find /lib/libc.so.6 even after sysroot set

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I am trying to cross-compile a simple C program with [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/) for `arm-linux-gnueabi` on Windows 10 `x86_64`, using toolchains and sysroots [provided by Linaro](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/5.5-2017.10/arm-linux-gnueabi/).

The tools I use in compilation:

- **Build suite:** Cmake 3.23.2
- **Make tool:** [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) 1.10.2
- **Build toolchain:** Linaro GCC 5.5, as above
- **IDE:** CLion 2022.2

My cross compile configuration `.cmake` file:

```py
# User's variables
set(USER_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT "D:/gcc")
set(USER_CROSS_SYSROOT "D:/sysroot")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${USER_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${USER_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.exe")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${USER_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}"
        "${USER_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/arm-linux-gnueabi"
        )
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${USER_CROSS_SYSROOT}")


set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

As you see, `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is defined in the file above.

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(gtkHelloWorld C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

link_directories(lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE libgtk-x11-2.0.so libgdk-x11-2.0.so libXrender.so libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so libpangocairo-1.0.so libXdamage.so libXfixes.so libatk-1.0.so libpng16.so libxcb-shm.so libxcb-render.so libX11.so libgio-2.0.so libpangoft2-1.0.so libfontconfig.so libfreetype.so libz.so libexpat.so libffi.so libgmodule-2.0.so libgthread-2.0.so libglib-2.0.so)
```

`path/to/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe -{PARAMETERS BELOW...} -print-search-dirs` prints (formatted):

```
...
Library:
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/
D:/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/
D:/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/
D:/sysroot/lib/
D:/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/
D:/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/
D:/sysroot/usr/lib/
```

## Problem

Everything had been fine until I tried to compile the binary.

**I got errors like:**

```bash
arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /lib/ld-linux.so.3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The minimal command to reproduce the error:

```
path/to/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe \

--sysroot=D:/sysroot \
-g CMakeFiles/gtkHelloWorld.dir/main.c.o \
-LD:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib \
-lgtk-x11-2.0  -lgdk-x11-2.0  -lXrender  -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0  -lpangocairo-1.0  -lXdamage  -lXfixes  -latk-1.0 -lpng16  -lxcb-shm  -lxcb-render  -lX11  -lgio-2.0  -lpangoft2-1.0  -lfontconfig  -lfreetype  -lz  -lexpat  -lffi  -lgmodule-2.0  -lgthread-2.0  -lglib-2.0
```

`-v` option prints (formatted):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\gcc\bin\arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ...

Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.5.0 (Linaro GCC 5.5-2017.10)
COMPILER_PATH=
d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/;
d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/;
d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/;
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/

LIBRARY_PATH=
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/;
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/;
d:/gcc/lib/gcc/;
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/;
D:/sysroot/lib/;
D:/sysroot/usr/lib/

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-LD:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib' '-v' '-march=armv7-a' '-mtune=cortex-a9' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'

d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/collect2.exe \
-plugin d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll \
-plugin-opt=d:/gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/lto-wrapper.exe \
-plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\w568w\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWU1Lgv.res \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
--sysroot=D:/sysroot \
--build-id --eh-frame-hdr \
-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.3 \
-X -m armelf_linux_eabi D:/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o D:/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/crtbegin.o \
-LD:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib \
-Ld:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0 \
-Ld:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi \
-Ld:/gcc/lib/gcc \
-Ld:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib \
-LD:/sysroot/lib \
-LD:/sysroot/usr/lib \
CMakeFiles/gtkHelloWorld.dir/main.c.o \
-rpath D:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib \
-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lXrender -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXdamage -lXfixes -latk-1.0 -lpng16 -lxcb-shm -lxcb-render -lX11 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lz -lexpat -lffi -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_ \
--no-as-needed d:/gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.5.0/crtend.o D:/sysroot/usr/lib/crtn.o

(...A lot of "attempt to open" and "succeeded"...)

opened script file D:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/libc.so.6 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a failed
attempt to open /lib/ld-linux.so.3 failed

d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
d:/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /lib/ld-linux.so.3

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file appeared in the output above, `D:/Code/gtkHelloWorld/lib/libc.so` is:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-linux.so.3 ) )
```

What confuses me is that, **all answers I could find tell me to add `--sysroot=` (or `-Wl,--sysroot=`), which I have done from the beginning.**

Also, I can confirm that the three .so files *exactly* exist at `{SYS_ROOT}/lib` and `{SYS_ROOT}/usr/lib`.

I suppose that the linker *does* notice the `sysroot`, because removing `--sysroot=` from the command will produce another error saying `cannot find crt1.o`.

## The answers I have tried but failed

1. [cannot find /lib/libc.so.6 even after setting sysroot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23871439/7812435) : Add `-Wl` before `--sysroot`
2. [Cannot find /lib/libc.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964880/cannot-find-lib-libc-so-6) : Add `--sysroot`
3. [cannot find /lib64/libc.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510046/cannot-find-lib64-libc-so-6) : Same situation, still no answer

Comment: Try -v or --verbose to cmd line to see what gcc/ld tries to do.

Comment: Obvious things to check. Is there /lib/libc.so.6 under sysroot? Is it a library for the right architecture?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have added the verbose output to the problem. And yes, `libc.so.6` is at `D:/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6`, and `file` says it is a `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3 for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, with debug_info, not stripped`

Comment: For some reason `-v` doesn't do much for `ld`. Try `-Wl,--verbose`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. New logs from `ld` are appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m and @infinitezero for giving advice on how to debug this problem. Now I can answer it by myself.

The crucial point is that **`ld.exe` does not always follow `SYS_ROOT` or see it as a virtual filesystem root.**

It services as a shortcut for including a complete set of headers and libraries (usually useful when doing cross compilation). The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) says:

> --sysroot=*dir*
>
> Use *dir* as the logical root directory for headers and libraries. For example, if the compiler normally searches for headers in `/usr/include` and libraries in `/usr/lib`, it instead searches `dir/usr/include` and `dir/usr/lib`.

**But the document omits some special rules.** As was discussed [here](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2020-May/141575.html),

> You misunderstand GNU `ld`'s `--sysroot` rule, which is applicable in these two cases:
>
> - when a path begins with `=` or `$SYSROOT`
> - (Only) in case a sysroot prefix is configured, and **the filename starts with
>   the ‘/’ character**, and **the script being processed was located inside
>   the sysroot prefix**, the filename will be looked for in the sysroot
>   prefix.

Otherwise, `ld` will **only** look at the absolute path defined in the script (`/lib/xxx`), instead of `{SYS_ROOT}/lib/xxx`.

So a quick fix for my problem is to change the ld script `gtkHelloWorld/lib/libc.so` in my project to

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( =/lib/libc.so.6 =/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( =/lib/ld-linux.so.3 ) )
```

Then it compiles normally.

**Ref:** for those who'd like to explore more about ld script, [this](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Simple-Commands.html) is a comprehensive doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your cmake file

```
find_library(LIB_C "libc" HINTS ${USER_SYSROOT}/lib)
message(STATUS "LIB: ${LIB_C}")
```

To get an idea if cmake can find it. Then just add ${LIB_C} to `target_link_libraries`

Comment: CMake finds the library at the correct path successfully. But `target_link_libraries` does seem to notify `ld.exe` of the path. It produces the same errors. I doubt that since some libraries referenced by GTK-2.0 are using `GNU ld script` to look for a group of `.so` files, `ld.exe` fails to use `SYS_ROOT` as a clue to find the libraries.